# Perl: redirect two sockets in each other

Tags: perl, sockets, redirect

Here is what I want to do:

- create two sockets S1 and S2
- redirect the output of S1 to the input of S2
- redirect the output of S2 to the input of S1

In C, I would have take a look somewhere around "dup2" and others, but I really do not know how I can do that in Perl.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the documentation for `open()` -- all of the functionality of `dup()` can be done with `open` - e.g.:

```
open(my $fh2, '<&=', $fh1); # makes $fh2 a dup of file handle $fh1
```

On the other hand, I think you can accomplish your goal by making a distinction between read handles and write handles. I.e., in your code don't use the same socket handle for both reading and writing - use different variables/instance members/parameters to specify a read handle and a write handle. Example - instead of:

```
sub foo {
  my ($sock) = @_;
  my $x = <$sock>;
  ...
  print {$sock} ...;
}
```

write your code like this:

```
sub foo {
  my ($rh, $wh) = @_;
  my $x = <$rh>;   # use $rh for reading
  ...
  print {$wh} ...; # use $wh for writing
}
```

Then if you really can use the same socket, you call `foo` with `foo($sock, $sock)`.
However, if you want to use two different sockets, then you can it with `foo($s1, $s2)`.